# HOW TO INSTALL pyinotify TO python3.3 ENVIRONMENT?

Tags: python

I compiled Python 2.7 and Python 3.3.3 in my VPS.
The compilation of Python 2.7 is:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2  
cd Python-2.7.3
./configure 
make            
make install
```

The compilation of Python 3.3 is:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf Python-3.3.3.tar.bz2  
cd Python-3.3.3
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python-3.3.3
make            
make install 
ln -s /usr/local/python-3.3.3/bin/python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python3.3

as3:/usr/local/python-3.3.3/lib/python3.3# python3.3 letterpress.py ~/letterpress/press_folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "letterpress.py", line 27, in
import pyinotify
ImportError: No module named 'pyinotify'
as3:/usr/local/python-3.3.3/lib/python3.3# pip install pyinotify
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyinotify in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyinotify-0.9.4-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
as3:/usr/local/python-3.3.3/lib/python3.3#
```

In the above, pyinotify is installed to Python 2.7 environment, now how can I install pyinotify to Python 3.3 environment?

Comment: ummm, may I ask what distribution are you using?

https://launchpad.net/~fta/+archive/dev

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-rebuilds/+archive/py3.3/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75

ubuntu has 3.3 python supported in their ppa

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: @oefe. Are you sure you got the right duplicate?

Comment: Oops, no, this doesn't make sense. Don't know what went wrong here, sorry. So I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to install a second copy of `pip` using your Python 3 instance.  Then use that `pip` to install a copy of `pynotify` for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
Check here: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

```
git clone https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify.git
cd pyinotify
python3.3 setup.py install
```

(thus I can install pyinotify to python3.3 environment successfully)

or:

```
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python3.3 distribute_setup.py
```

it will show:

```
...
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/python-3.3.3/bin
Installing easy_install-3.3 script to /usr/local/python-3.3.3/bin
...
```

/usr/local/python-3.3.3/bin/easy_install-3.3 pyinotify 
(thus I can install pyinotify to python3.3 environment successfully)

Comment: I receive a 404 Nor Found with wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py